# Is there any other way possible to read a file status in C without using stat() function?

Tags: c, linux

Is there any other way possible to read a file status in C without using stat() function? I'm doing some research around the Internet but can't find one? Any answers would help a lot! Thank you.

Comment: In Linux, you could make the raw syscall, but _why_?

Comment: Using `fstatat()` instead?

Answer (score 2):

As my comment mentions, you can use the raw syscall if you know the calling convention. The question still remains: why would you do that? :)

Since you were asking for any other way than the usual route, the example below purposely doesn't use any symbolic constants or structures, but here are some hints...

- I know the syscall number for `stat` is 4.
- I know the call expects a pointer to a pathname and a pointer to memory to write the information to.

  - I know a `struct stat` is 144 bytes, so 256 bytes allocated on the stack is enough.
  - I know the offset of `st_size` in that structure is 48 bytes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  char buf[256];
  if (argc < 2)
    exit(2);
  if (syscall(4, argv[1], buf) != 0)
    exit(10);
  printf("%s is %d bytes\n", argv[1], *(int *)(buf + 48));
}
```

Running in a Linux box:

```
root@4a4740c47031:/zoop# ls -la
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root   96 Oct 15 08:50 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Oct 15 08:39 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  255 Oct 15 08:46 zoop.c
root@4a4740c47031:/zoop# gcc -Wall -o zoop ./zoop.c && ./zoop ./zoop.c
./zoop.c is 255 bytes
root@4a4740c47031:/zoop#
```

Comment: That's a helpful response. Thank you for helping though it seems a bit wierd why would I use other way instead of stat, it's because my educational purposes and need to research about it. Still big thanks to you..